# Unable to insert node into linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the following code. The purpose is, that each node stores an index, and I wish to insert the node into the list in ascending order. For example, if the list currently has 1, 3, 4, 8, 9 and 10, I wish to be able to insert a node with index 2 such that it is 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9 and 10.

```
void createNode(int index) {
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode->index = index;
    traverse(newNode, head);
}
```

This creates the node and stores index value.

```
void traverse(Node *newN, Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        newN->next = NULL;
        head = newN;
    }
    else if (head->index < newN->index) {
        newN->next = head->next;
        head->next = newN;
    }
    else
    traverse(newN, head->next);
}
```

This is a recursive function to traverse through the list and find the location to insert the node. If head is null, I assume either the list is empty (or seeing as this function is recursive, it has reached the end of the list). Otherwise it checks for any values higher than its index, and upon encountering it, should insert itself behind it.

```
void display(Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) return;
    cout << head->data << " " << head->index << "   ";
    display(head->next);
}
```

And this should display it. However nothing shows up for me. Debugging with a cout on each if condition to see what executes shows that the first if condition keeps executing. But nothing is written into the list.

Any help, much appreciated.

Update:

```
void createNode(int index) {
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode->index = index;
    if (head == NULL) {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        head = newNode;
    }
    traverse(newNode, head);
}

void traverse(Node *newN, Node *head) {
    if (head->index < newN->index) {
        newN->next = head->next;
        head->next = newN;
    }
    else
    traverse(newN, head->next);
}
```

This works, so I'm guessing not a pointer problem?

Comment: `head` is pointer being passed to `traverse()` ... you'll need its address if you want to change its value.  It also appears as a global in `createNode()`, which is worrying

Comment: traverse and display are recursives, so display(Node *head) executes again within itself with display(head->next). so I suppose I'm passing it because it creates a placeholder in the parameters of the function so I can keep passing different values, and since it starts from head

Comment: and no, not a global, these are all methods in a class and head is also inside the class

Comment: Assigning to a parameter has no effect outside the function - there is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Note that recursion is likely to cause stackoverflows on large lists and is also much slower then an iterative approach.

Comment: BTW: "traversing" a list usually implies that its structure doesn't change. A better name would be "insert".

Comment: Unrelated, but your current algo generates 1->3->2 when you successively insert 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes this is true, just tried it. Thanks for pointing it out! any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: You must insert the new node when `head->index < newN->index` **and** `newN->index <= head->next->index`. Your current code has forgotten that second condition.

Comment: @SergeBallesta causes an error, I'm guessing since there's not that many nodes when writing initially, so trying to read nonexisting head->next :(

Comment: Yes, I did not mention the or `head->next == NULL` in the second condition... But hopefully you detected it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not changing anything with:

```
head = newN;
```

because it's passed in as:

```
void traverse(Node *newN, Node *head) {
```

if you need to change it then you need to pass in a reference to the pointer:

```
void traverse(Node *newN, Node *&head) {
```

You also shouldn't be using raw pointers such as `Node *head`, use a smart poiner instead.

Comment: seems that reference to pointers are not allowed in c++?

Comment: `Node &*` is a typo; it should be `Node *&`.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem, but moving the first part of the if condition out to createNode seems to work. I have no idea why though.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks - typo fixed.